# Hypothesis testing with binary pattern

Tags: discrete-signals

Let's say you have a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i = 1}^N$ of ones and zeros. You know that $P(x_i = 1) = \frac{1}{3}$.

You want to test two hypotheses

$H_0$: The sequence is $iid$ with $P(x_i = 1) \ \forall \ i$

$H_1$: The sequence is full of $001$ sub-sequences, but has noise. For example, the sequence might start off as $001001$, then have a period of random noise (where $P(x_i = 1) = \frac{1}{3}$).

After the period of noise, the sequence matches the $001001$ pattern again. Importantly, the $1$ values might land on different values than when it started.

That is, we are not testing whether $mod(i, 3) = 0 \implies x_i = 1$. We are merely testing whether the "normal" state of this sequence is batches of $001001001$ but those batches could start at any value.

Another way of putting this is that we allow for "extra" bits to be inserted.

Ideally, I would like to find a test statistic that enables me to reject the null in this scenario. One possible solution, suggested in the comments below, is to count the number of $001$ sequences, and compare to the number of $001$ sequences you would find under the null.

This is an interesting solution. I will have to think more about how one might construct a confidence interval or assymptotics for this statistic.

I appreciate your comments.

Update: After thinking about the scenario that we are working with more, I think I can safely assume that only $0$ values are inserted. This is a much simpler problem.

$H_0$: The sequence is $iid$ with $P(x_i = 1) = \sum_{i = 1}^N x_i$. We guess it's Bernoulli distributed according to the number of $1$s we observe in the data.

$H_1$: The sequence has lots of $001001001$ segments, but extra $0$ values get *inserted* at random into the sequence (which creates offsets as above).

I don't think this materially changes the approach too much, but means we no longer need to worry about the distribution of the "Noise" sequences.

Comment: Think carefully about _what_ you want to conclude. "On average, one-third of the bits are 1, rest are 0" is not the same as "Every third bit is a 1, rest are 0".  The latter is true if and only if the sequence is $001001001001\cdots$ which is easy to test for; the former is true not only for $001001001001\cdots$ but also for $0010000000111\cdots$ as well as for numerous other sequences. What do you wish to test for?

Comment: Thanks for asking about the clarification. I definitely want to reject the sequence $0010000000111$. Recall that after errors, the sequence "re-starts" doing $001001001$, but the placement of $1$s might not be the same. I.e. before, you might have $1$ at $1, 4, 7$. Then $8$ is an errant $0$. After this, you would expect $1$ at $9, 12, 15...$.

Comment: Hi: you can use the test of proportions where, in this  $p = 1$. under the null. But be careful here because $\hat{p}$ will be the number of 001 sequences out of the total number of three digit sequences. So, if you had  say,  000001001000, then this is four three digit sequences and two of the four are 001 so your $\hat{p} = 2/4 = 0.5$. From there, you can carry out the proportions test at whatever significance level you choose. If you are not familiar with the test, any intro stat book will explain the steps. The only catch for your is what $\hat{p}$ is which I explained above.

Comment: Are you assuming that you know the alignment of where the $1$s should be?

Comment: Also would you ever allow a slip?  I.E.  An extra or missing bit.

Comment: Hi: Yes, The approach described assumes that there is supposed to be a 1 in the third position and 2 zeros in the first and second position. So, I assumed that the correct alignment was known. As far as an extra or missing bit, no, it doesn't allow for that because how would know that a that one was missing or extra ? Here is an example of a test of proportions. But, as far as handling a missing or extra, unless there's a way of knowing that, I don't think there's an existing test that could handle it. https://online.stat.psu.edu/statprogram/reviews/statistical-concepts/proportions

Comment: >  The approach described assumes that there is supposed to be a 1 in the third position and 2 zeros in the first and second position. This is the assumption I need to avoid. However I think "counting the number of `001` sequences is still a good approach. I just have a larger `N`, since the `N` is the total number of 3-digit sequences, which may overlap. Maybe it's somewhat related to those coin flip examples, looking for the first sequence of a  $HHT$ etc. At least the correction for `N`.

Comment: One more thing:  if you do use the test for proportions, your denominator will crash because the proportion under the null hypothesis,  $p_{0} = 1$. So, that expression in the denominator will be zero under the null.  One way to deal with that is to use $p = 0.5$ just in  the denominator. Doing this,  maximizes the value of the denominator and thereby maximizes the estimate of the variance which can't hurt because it makes you less likely to reject the null when its true. It's just a fix to deal with the fact that you have a strange value of the proportion under the null.

Comment: Hi: I'm not clear on what you're testing because I thought that the null hypothesis was that any 3 digit sequence was supposed to be 001. If it's not, then what I described does not apply.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear on the null hypothesis. I think the null hypothesis, in this case, would be that the sequence has $1/3$ of the values $1$ but those are distributed at random, not in bunches of `001` sequences. EDIT: I guess Null can be `001001...` as well. Ideally I'd like to show that it *is* `001001` rather than random. But i'd settle for just not rejecting the null.

Comment: @genauguy this is getting kinda long to read through. Could you take all the clarifications that were worked out in these comments and edit your question to incorporate them, and be as precise. Actually name all hypotheses; use math notation when it's clearer than words can be etc. Thank you!

Comment: yes. I think Marcus has a good point. Maybe an example might help also. In other words, make up some sequence and then explain which ones are viewed as good 3 digit sequences and which ones are not. If you just want them to add up to 1, then that means that 001, 100, 010 are all good sequences ? In that case, you can still use a proportions test  but when you calculate $\hat{p}$, you need to count those sequencse as good sequences. Still, unless you know when there's a missing digit or extra digit, there's no way to handle that.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect this conversation. yes, $001$ $100$ and $010$ are all "good" sequences. This just leaves "bad" sequences as $000$, $110$, $111$, $011$. I can try and work through the math on this, as well as some simulations.

Comment: Hi, all. I've edited my question again. After thinking more about the data I am working with, I think we can assume all the "noise" insertions are $0$s.

Comment: If I understand you, you have a set of numbers built from 0 and 1. Empirically 1 shows up 1/3 of the samples. You want a measure how probable to be a random set with probability of 1 to be 1/3 or generated from 001?

Comment: yes, that is the set-up.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you explained, you can count the number of times the sequence is
001, 100 or 010. Then, $\hat{p}$ is defined as that count divided by the number of sequences, $N$.

If we define the null as the hypothesis that the proportion of good sequences  is 1.0,  then the test is

$H_0: p = 1.0$ versus $H_1: p \neq 1.0$

As far as testing the null, ( I'm assuming N is large here so that the normal
approximation to the binomial holds )  you can calculate the test statistic

as $Z =  \frac{ \hat{p} - p_{0}}{\sqrt{\frac{\bar{p}(1-\bar{p})}{N}}}$

and use $p_{0} = 1 $ and $\bar{p} = 0.5$. Then, reject the null if $|Z| > Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ where $\alpha$ is the critical value of the test.

The CI  would be $\hat{p} ~ \pm Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \times 
{\sqrt{\frac{\bar{p}(1-\bar{p})}{N}}}$.

If a digit in one of the three digit sequences is is missing or there's an extra, and you know this, then you can just count that sequence as a bad sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much! One question. Our sequence is not IID. Given that you observe `001`, the probability that the next sequence is `010` is quite high. If I assume that this sequence is ergodic (which I think just requires something mild about our the "noise" periods, then maybe I can just take a random sample of spaced out trios, right? Those are as good as independent.

Comment: Hi: If the three digit sequences are not independent, then the proportions test can't be used. But I think what you're referring to as a fix to this is to randomly sample the sequences in order to sort of make them indepedent ?  This sounds reasonable but you'll need a lot of sample data. I'm not sure why you refer to simulations ? Do you not have actual data ?

Comment: No, we do have actual data. Sorry by "random sample" I mean randomly selected subsets of the series.

Comment: yes, you can sample with replacement to hopefully deal with the correlation. Note that this is called bootstrapping so you may want to google for an intro to that if you're not familar with the approach. You will sample to get what is a referred to ad a "boostrapped statistic" and then use that to test your hypothesis, construct a CI etc. The underlying distribution is no longer binomial ( because of the correlation ) but the boostrapped distribution can be used to test the hypothesis. There are some good intros out there. If you can't find one, let me know and I can try to find one.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with bootstrapping. I should have connected the dots there.I will attempt this!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to describe a discrete hidden Markov chain `X` with
hidden states (let's name them 1,2,3) and transition matrix

```
λ*[0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 0 0] + (1 - λ)*ones(3,3)/3
```

and observation operator

```
H(x) = x == 3
```

If `λ == 1`, you have a deterministic `1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3` latent sequence and
will observe `0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1...`. If `λ == 1`, the latent states are i.i.d `1 2 1 2 3 3 2 1 3` and you'll observe an i.d.d sequence of `0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1...`

If you put a prior on `λ`, you can use Bayesian inference to estimate it, or otherwise maximum likelihood if you want. Related: Baum-Welch algorithm.

You can play with

````
using Random, LinearAlgebra, Distributions, StatsBase

P =  λ*[0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 0 0] + (1 - λ)*ones(3,3)/3 
"""
      samplefrom(p)

Produces a sample from the probability distribution
with prob .mass vector p.

Helpful: to sample from the conditional distribution given state i

    j = samplefrom(P[i, :]) # : for all j

"""
samplefrom(p) = sample(1:3, weights(p))

"""
      samplefromchain(p, P, n)

Samples an n-step Markov chain with starting distribution p
with transition matrix P.
"""
function samplefromchain(p, P, n) # n is number of trans
      s = samplefrom(p)
      statevector = [s]
      for i in 1:n
            s = samplefrom(P[s, :])
            push!(statevector, s)
      end
      return statevector
end
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach (less formal?) than @mschuaer.

1. Generate the autocorrelation of your sequence.
2. Shuffle your sequence by sampling from it without replacement (x1000)
3. Compare the actual autocorrelation with the shuffle.

[image: Cross correlation of noisy data with superimposed shuffles.]